# What does Petzold mean when he says the C# mantra is "Classes are reference types; structures are value types"?

Tags: c#, .net, value-type, reference-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between reference type and value type in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/difference-between-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Charles Petzold in his book ".Net book zero" has wrote the C# Mantra "Classes are reference types; structures are value types." how it helps, whats its need and what is it?

Comment: Read the following article: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html

Comment: It is a mantra, you have to repeat it a hundred times so you don't forget it.